# How to connect my website with DB2 on Cloud?

Tags: database, api, db2, rdbms

I have a site and there is register system that introduce data into RDBMS via php. I had PostgreSql on localhost and now I wanna connect my website with "DB2 on Cloud" from cloud.ibm.com 
**How can I do it and what I must use?** 
I used to connect with postgres via .php, but with db2 must I use JDBC,ODBC or other APIs? or with other things for RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IBM's  php_ibm_db2 module to connect a PHP website to a remote database on Db2-on-cloud.  This module uses an ODBC (also known as CLI in Db2) connection to the database, and it requires a CLI driver for the database connectivity, and such a driver is freely downloadable from IBM by following the instrucuctions).

You can use a classic interface or a PDO style interface, both are supported in php_ibm_db2.

You will have a learning curve, so careful study of all the documentation is necessary.

Depending on your platform, you may need to compile that module, but some precompiled modules are available.

See https://github.com/php/pecl-database-ibm_db2

See also https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2oc?topic=programmatically-php

Comment: If u can, can u give me some link with Rest API, because I think will be better to change php with python, how do u think?@mao